# Decomposing matrices to lower ranks

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra

Given real matrix $M\in\{0,1\}^{n\times n}$ of rank $r$. How many $M_i\in\{0,1\}^{n\times n}$ of rank $s$ does one need to write $M'=\sum_{i=1}^ta_iM_i$ for some $a_i\in\Bbb R$ where maximum absolute value entry of $M'-M$ is $\frac{1}{4}$? We know $t=n^2$ suffices. However can we do better (say in a number as a function of $r,s$)?

For instance consider $M$ to be block diagonal matrix with $2$ blocks of $1$. $r=2$ here and $M$ can indeed be given as sum of $2$ rank $s=1$ matrices.

Comment: You can use matrices that have at most s rows nonzero.   You can probably get close to r/s many summands.

Comment: remember I have error 1/4. we probably can do better?

Comment: Try it with a rank r identity matrix first.  I think you will not be able to keep the error bound.

Comment: Sorry I am misunderstanding. Could you explain better?

Comment: Let M be the zero matrix except having ones in entries a_ii for i from 1 to r.  Any matrix M' with entries within 1/4 of the entries of M should also have rank r or close to it.